# Provoking TestFlight/iTunes Connect into releasing new beta version

Tags: app-store-connect, testflight

I'm using the new beta version functionality in iTunes Connect. I uploaded a build (98) to iTunes Connect, set up some internal testers and they downloaded that build.

Now I've updated the build with a new version (build 99) and that's been uploaded to iTunes Connect, but I can't see how to provoke the system into pushing this new version out to the users and their TestFlight app.

I'm set up as a tester on a couple of devices (both with my developer ID as well as with another id) and I can still only see build 98.

On the iTunes Connect screen build 98 is listed as inactive (which is correct because it has been superseded by build 99), but build 99 only says 'invite testers', but I've invited all those I want to invite.

[image: screenshot]

It says that users will 'automatically receive new builds', but how long does it take? I was hoping it would be instant. Is there a way to provoke iTunes Connect into sending out the update notifications so my users can test the new version?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I'm not sure if this is a bug in TestFlight but toggle off and then on again the "TestFlight Beta Testing" switch. As soon as you do it all your internal testers should get notified of the new build. 
[image]

Another option is to simply go into the new Build Details and save it.

Comment: Bingo. That works - and pretty much instantaneously too. Certainly seems like a bug to me! Thanks so much.

Comment: If it is a bug I hope they don't fix it. After submitting an app into testing, you have to wait several minutes before you can enter in any testing info. So if it went live automatically, you have to time it right to make sure you can enter in the info before it gets pushed to your team. I like not having it go live before flipping the switch (or in this case twice).

Comment: FYI it looks like they unfortunately fixed this bug. So as soon as the build finishes processing it gets sent out to your beta testers.